# How do we KNOW that eliminating whitespace in HTML/JS/CSS files improves page load time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

How can we assume that unless we have the source code for the browser? After all, the browser might have been written in such a way that unnecessary whitespace actually improves the time it takes to parse the files. We can't assume that when browsers read those files they do something like

```
if (thischar == ' ') // do nothing
```

Comment: Because when you don't have any whitespaces, your file has less bytes, which means faster download rate... (or faster page load)

Comment: How would code with *extra* whitespace make parsing quicker? That makes no sense at all. It’s like saying that a truck with extra empty boxes can somehow be unloaded quicker.

Comment: Actually, we *do* know via publicly available source code and parsing guidelines available to us: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#tokenization. Is there any guarantee that everyone implements it exactly this way? Of course not. But for 99.99% of internet traffic, it's a safe assumption.

Comment: It does make me wonder if a compressed file (e.g. gzip) without minification is basically the same size as the minified file.  A good compression algorithm, I would assume, should produce a small file as well.  Also, often js, css are static files so compression could be done earlier.  is there really any advantage to minification other than obsfucation?

Comment: A compressed file is probably even smaller than a minified file. But a compressed minified file is probably smaller than a compressed non-minified file.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't about parsing, but load times. A smaller file (e.g. without whitespace byte overhead) will be transferred faster over a network.

As far as your parsing question goes, whitespace is generally ignored and the parsers most likely **do** have something akin to `if (thischar == ' ') continue;` but this computation is negligible.

Comment: But maybe they do ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know for sure. There is still the chance that you have a browser written that terribly that it is actually the browser not the download time which limits your speed. ;)

But if you could show us the source code for a html parser which speeds up proportionally to the amount of whitespaces in the input, you might well win a prize. All we had to do is to fill in extra white spaces into the received documents and...lightning fast! ;)

Comment: As unlikely as it is. Also, you could run an apple ][ on a Gigabit Ethernet, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could just measure it. But the added value of more spaces it unlikely. If you have ever written even a simple parser, you know that it doesn't make much sense that extra white space would make it faster. But moreover, larger files take longer to download, and networking speed is a bottleneck sooner than CPU power.

Comment: “doesn't make much sense” is an understatement. It makes no sense at all. Extra characters in the source text means more work for the parser.

Comment: But you guys are aware that there is the possibility that files are sent in a compressed manner, right? Then (a few) extra spaces might matter even less in terms of bandwidth. More interesting would be if there is actually some parallel universe in which parsers get faster if their scanner has to discard more whitespaces.

Comment: Sure, but compressed minified files are probably smaller or at least not larger than compressed non-minified files, so the same logic applies. It would be very interesting to have a parser that gets faster if it has to plough through more whitespace, but like I said, it's very unlikely. I've written parsers for various purposes, one of them being an actual production level scripting language, and I don't see how extra whitespace would make a parser faster, except when you deliberately write it like so (add delays when there is no whitespace).

Comment: Well, to be fair, one possibility crossed my mind. If you have a number of subsequent operators, like `x += ++x`, or other more complex expressions, I can imagine that without whitespace, a parser needs a more thorough lookahead to determine what is going one, while with whitespace, it might rule out some possibilities. But you would have to measure specific implementations to see if that's the case, and then still in practice it's unlikely that a script has so many of such expressions that it would tip the balance in the other direction. It would be an interesting experiment though...